# adding special characters to database?

Tags: mysql

I'm having problems getting special characters like apostrophes and such from being added into my database.

I have the following code that adds data from a form into my database.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO people(`ID`, `Name`, `Description`)
 VALUES (NULL, '$name', '$desc')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Form code looks like so:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM people";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($person = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<h3>" . $person['Name'] . "</h3>";
echo "<p>" .$person['Description'] . "</p>"}`
```

How would I go about fixing this so that the string field accepts special characters?

Comment: try using `mysql_real_escape_string()` function

Comment: Update from the [deprecated/legacy `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) and [prevent SQL injection by using parameterized queries](http://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/2864740) (suggestions to use mysql_real_escape_string are a hack for code that *should* be updated anyway)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use **`mysql_real_escape_string`**

```
$insert_data = mysql_real_escape_string($input_data);
```

Assuming that you have the data stored as $input_data

Answer (score 3):

if you want add special character in MySQL database use

> mysql_real_escape_string($name)

after that insert into database

Answer (score 0):

Just use mysql_real_escape_string

```
 $insert_data = mysql_real_escape_string($input_data);
```

Assuming that you have the data stored as $input_data